# Must declare the scalar variable "@EXPORTSTATUS1"

Tags: c#, sql

I have a program that exports sql data into text files. In my code, I want to check if the files were successfully created/exported, and if they were, insert that into an sql table. My project builds fine, however I receive "Must declare the scalar variable "@EXPORTSTATUS1"."
I haven't been able to figure out why. My code is below.

```
    string connectionStringlast = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
        using (SqlConnection _conman = new SqlConnection(connectionStringlast))
        {
                _conman.Open();
                //opens the predefined connection _con

                string exportdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt");
                string exportstatus = "Exported";

                string inserttheString = @"INSERT INTO EXPORT_TRACKER
                    (EXPORT_DATE, T1STATUS, T2STATUS, T3STATUS, T4STATUS, T5STATUS, T6STATUS, T7STATUS, T8STATUS, T9STATUS, T10STATUS)
                    VALUES(@EXPORTDATE, @EXPORTSTATUS1, @EXPORTSTATUS2, @EXPORTSTATUS3, @EXPORTSTATUS4, @EXPORTSTATUS5, @EXPORTSTATUS6, @EXPORTSTATUS7, @EXPORTSTATUS8, @EXPORTSTATUS9, @EXPORTSTATUS10)";
                //defines the sql insert query to be performed 

                using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(inserttheString, _conman))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTDATE", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTDATE"].Value = exportdate;

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl1_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS1", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS1"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl2_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS2", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS2"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl3_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS3", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS3"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl4_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS4", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS4"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl5_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS5", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS5"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl6_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS6", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS6"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl7_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS7", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS7"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl8_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS8", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS8"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl9_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS9", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS9"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl10_export.txt"))
                    {
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS10", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS10"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }

                    cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //executes to insert query

                    _conman.Close();
                    //closes the no longer in use database connection
                }
            }
```

I've changed my code to the following, but am now receiving many instances of two errors. "expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct" and "the name cmd5 does not exist in the current context".

```
 string connectionStringlast = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
        using (SqlConnection _conman = new SqlConnection(connectionStringlast))
        {
                _conman.Open();
                //opens the predefined connection _con

                string exportdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt");
                string exportstatus = "Exported";

                string inserttheString = @"INSERT INTO EXPORT_TRACKER
                    (EXPORT_DATE, T1STATUS, T2STATUS, T3STATUS, T4STATUS, T5STATUS, T6STATUS, T7STATUS, T8STATUS, T9STATUS, T10STATUS)
                    VALUES(@EXPORTDATE, @EXPORTSTATUS1, @EXPORTSTATUS2, @EXPORTSTATUS3, @EXPORTSTATUS4, @EXPORTSTATUS5, @EXPORTSTATUS6, @EXPORTSTATUS7, @EXPORTSTATUS8, @EXPORTSTATUS9, @EXPORTSTATUS10)";
                //defines the sql insert query to be performed 

                using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(inserttheString, _conman))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTDATE", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTDATE"].Value = exportdate;
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS1", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS2", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS3", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS4", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS5", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS6", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS7", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS8", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS9", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS10", SqlDbType.NChar);


                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl1_export.txt"))
                    {           
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS1"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl2_export.txt"))
                    {                            
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS2"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl3_export.txt"))
                    {                          
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS3"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl4_export.txt"))
                    {                           
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS4"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl5_export.txt"))
                    {                            
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS5"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl6_export.txt"))
                    {                           
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS6"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl7_export.txt"))
                    {                            
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS7"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl8_export.txt"))
                    {                          
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS8"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl9_export.txt"))

                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS9"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl10_export.txt"))
                    {                          
                        cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS10"].Value = exportstatus;
                    }

                    cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //executes to insert query

                    _conman.Close();
                    //closes the no longer in use database connection
                }
            }
```

I fixed those errors, an if was missing a closing bracket. Now it builds, but i receive a different error upon execution.

"The parameterized query '(@EXPORTDATE nchar(22),@EXPORTSTATUS1 nchar(4000),@EXPORTSTATUS2' expects the parameter '@EXPORTSTATUS1', which was not supplied."

I got it working. I had to add else statements to bypass the error of the if returning false. Solution is below. Thanks for the help!!!!!!!

```
string connectionStringlast = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
        using (SqlConnection _conman = new SqlConnection(connectionStringlast))
        {
            _conman.Open();
            //opens the predefined connection _con

            string exportdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt");
            string exportstatus = "Exported";

            string inserttheString = @"INSERT INTO EXPORT_TRACKER
                    (EXPORT_DATE, T1STATUS, T2STATUS, T3STATUS, T4STATUS, T5STATUS, T6STATUS, T7STATUS, T8STATUS, T9STATUS, T10STATUS)
                    VALUES(@EXPORTDATE, @EXPORTSTATUS1, @EXPORTSTATUS2, @EXPORTSTATUS3, @EXPORTSTATUS4, @EXPORTSTATUS5, @EXPORTSTATUS6, @EXPORTSTATUS7, @EXPORTSTATUS8, @EXPORTSTATUS9, @EXPORTSTATUS10)";
            //defines the sql insert query to be performed 

            using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(inserttheString, _conman))
            {
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTDATE", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTDATE"].Value = exportdate;
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS1", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS2", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS3", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS4", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS5", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS6", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS7", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS8", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS9", SqlDbType.NChar);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS10", SqlDbType.NChar);


                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl1_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS1"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS1"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl2_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS2"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS2"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl3_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS3"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS3"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl4_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS4"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS4"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl5_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS5"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS5"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl6_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS6"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS6"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl7_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS7"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS7"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl8_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS8"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS8"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl9_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS9"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS9"].Value = "";
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl10_export.txt"))
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS10"].Value = exportstatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS10"].Value = "";
                }

                cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //executes to insert query

                _conman.Close();
                //closes the no longer in use database connection
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: just use [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Parameter[...

Comment: I think your `File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl1_export.txt")` returns `false` and that's why this parameter value wouldn't added to your `SqlCommand`. Did you debug your code?

Comment: You should always *add* the parameters and just make the assignment of the `Value` the bit that's conditional.

Comment: correct, the only files that actually exist atm are tbl5_export.txt and 8. i thought it could just skip it and move on if the file doesn't exist. how do i prevent this error in cases where the file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

The file specified here `C:\\BillingExport\\tbl1_export.txt` probably doesn't exist or the path is incorrect so the parameter is not added.

I would still add the parameter but without a value:

```
cmd5.Parameters.Add("@EXPORTSTATUS1", SqlDbType.NChar);
if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl1_export.txt"))
{
     cmd5.Parameters["@EXPORTSTATUS1"].Value = exportstatus;
}
```